Is it possible to get the filetype based on the filename without the need of loading the file?
I am wondering if it is possible to get the filetype based on the file name without the need of loading such a file? For example, if my filename is foo.py is there any way to get python without the need of loading foo.py in some buffer and then check its &filetype value?
As a workaround I am using a dictionary such that the keys are file extensions and the values are Vim filetypes, but there must be a better way I guess.

Some filetypes are detected by more (or different) than the extension. I think the most exact way is to run Vim, sadly.

You might map the output of the file program to Vim's filetypes. However, I'm not sure if there's much to be gained compared to opening the file in Vim.

In Vim file types are set by commands in filetypedetect group. It is not possible to pull all info directly from live code but still some basic parsing could be applied.
function! GetFt_by_aug(fname) abort
    " build lookup list once [[pat1, ft1], [pat2, ft2], ...]
    if !has_key(s:, 'ftinfo')
        " match group=filetypedetect, event=BufRead and cmd=setf[iletype] [filetype]
        " (1455 items matched out of 3524/2 approx.)
        let l:ic = &fic ? '\c' : '\C'
        let s:ftinfo = autocmd_get(#{group: 'filetypedetect'})
            \ ->filter({_, v -> v.event ==# 'BufRead' && v.cmd =~# '^setf\%[iletype]'})
            \ ->map({_, v -> [l:ic .. glob2regpat(v.pattern), v.cmd->matchstr('\w\+$')]})
    endif

    " try all known patterns
    for [l:pat, l:ft] in s:ftinfo
        if a:fname =~ l:pat
            return l:ft
        endif
    endfor

    " no match
    return ''
endfunction

:echo GetFt_by_aug('foo.py')
: " python

:echo GetFt_by_aug('bar.h')
: " <empty>

:echo GetFt_by_aug('/path/to/vim/doc/help.txt')
: " help

However, just going through the normal auto-detection procedure could be much easier. If you need to avoid loading anything from disk at all cost you can fake it with :h :file command though the results will become a bit less accurate.
function! GetFt_by_empty_buffer(fname) abort
    " just return &filetype if buffer was already loaded
    if bufloaded(a:fname)
        return getbufvar(a:fname, '&filetype')
    endif

    new
    try
        " the `file' command never reads file data from disk
        " (but may read path/directory contents)
        " however the detection will become less accurate
        " as some types cannot be recognized for empty files
        noautocmd silent execute 'file' fnameescape(a:fname)
        filetype detect
        return &filetype
    finally
        bwipeout!
    endtry
endfunction

:echo GetFt_by_empty_buffer('foo.py')
: " python

:echo GetFt_by_empty_buffer('bar.h')
: " c or cpp

:echo GetFt_by_empty_buffer('/path/to/vim/doc/help.txt')
: " help


As indicated by @DBenKnoble the filetype of a buffer is determined by Vim by looking at the extension of the file but also by looking at the content of the file.
That being said you can filter the output of the autocmd BufRead to update your dictionary:
Verbose au bufread
g/BufRead/d
g/Last set from/d
%s/\v\n {14}\ze\S/ /
g!/setf /d
g!/^\s*\S\+\s\+setf\s\+\S\+$/d
sort

On my configuration it produce a list of 1468 lines:
    *.-sst    setf sisu
    *.-sst.meta setf sisu
    *..ch     setf chill
    *.4gh     setf fgl
    *.4gl     setf fgl
...
    yarn.lock setf yaml
    yarn.lock setf yaml
    zathurarc setf zathurarc
    zathurarc setf zathurarc
    {,.}gitolite.rc setf perl
    {.,}makepkg.conf setf sh
    {.,}pylintrc setf dosini
    {.,}ripgreprc setf conf
    {.,}tmux*.conf setf tmux
    {.,}tmux*.conf* setf tmux
    {neo,}mutt[[:alnum:]._-]\\\{6\} setf mail
    {pending,completed,undo}.data setf taskdata

You could use that list to associate to file pattern a filetype
It will not give 100% the same output as Vim but it will be a good approximation.

This is solution is actually superseded by the solution of @Matt that implement it in Vimscript. I let it in only for educational purpose :-)

Based on the previous answers, I also come up with my own solution. Not perfect, but it does the job in many cases:
vim9script

def GetExtension2FiletypeDict(): dict<string>
  var tmp = split(execute('au bufread'), "\n")
  tmp ->filter( 'v:val !~ "BufRead" || v:val !~ "Last set from" ')
    # select only lines that start with '*.foo' and that contain 'setf '
    ->filter('v:val =~ "^\\s*\\*\\." &&  v:val =~ "setf "')
    # Put the results in the form 'foo:bar'
    ->map((_, val) => substitute(val, '\v\s*\*\.(\w*)\s*setf\s(\w*)', '\1:\2', 'g'))
    # select only results that of the form 'foo:bar' and NOT '  foo:  bar if something | bla bla | etc'
    ->filter('v:val =~ "^\\w\\+"')

  var mydict = {}
  for val in tmp
    var parts = split(val, ':')
    mydict[parts[0]] = parts[1]
  endfor

  return mydict
enddef

var ext2ft = GetExtension2FiletypeDict()

# test
echom get(ext2ft, 'py', '')

The obtained dictionary ext2ft has 804 key-value pairs.
